# Tensorflow image classification - eating up my memory

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, tensorflow

I am trying to write a small program which is able to classify certain pictures into categories. I create a list with pictures in the main code and pass them to the function in a loop. Code is working perfectly fine except for the fact that it does not free my memory and with each iteration the program uses more until it completely crashes.

Already tried to use "gc.collect()" in the function to force it to clear the memory, but that does not help. Shouldn't the memory be cleared automatically after checking one file or did I miss anything here?

```
def classify_pictures(self, files):

    os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

        # Read the image_data
        image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(files, 'rb').read()

        # Loads label file, strips off carriage return
        label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line
                   in tf.gfile.GFile("tf_files/retrained_labels.txt")]

        # Unpersists graph from file
        with tf.gfile.FastGFile("tf_files/retrained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
            graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
            graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
            _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

        with tf.Session() as sess:
            # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
            softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

            predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
                               {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})

            # Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
            top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

        for each_picture in range(0, 10):

            human_string = label_lines[top_k[0]]

            if human_string == "selfie":
                return ("selfie")

            if "passport" in human_string:
                return("passport")

            if "statement" in human_string:
                return("bill")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call this function in a loop the computational graph is being rebuild on every iteration and the previous graph is of course still there too. That is what uses all the memory.

To solve this only do the `session.run()` call inside the loop.

In general when writing Tensorflow code you should always try to keep code that generates the graph separate from code which executes the graph. In your case you are doing both inside a single function, which is than called multiple times so a new graph is rebuild every time.

Comment: Thanks, Alexander! I have moved parts of the code ("with tf.gfile.FastGFile" and "label_lines" part) out of the function/loop which did help a lot, but still not fix the issue completely. It slows down the memory usage drastically, but for processing a bigger amount of files it still ends up with using all memory at some point. Any idea? I am sure I am still missing something?

Comment: I can't be sure without seeing your full code, but I suspect that might be a Python leak, not Tensorflow. You might want to try only loading one set of images into the CPU RAM using Python, end executing the prediction on that one set over and over again. If that resolves the memory leak you know it's a Python leak (assuming the memory you are talking about is CPU not GPU memory).

Comment: Thanks again. I also removed:

#with tf.Session() as sess ...
#softmax_tensor = ....

Looks like this fixed the issue. Will try a bit more, but looks good now. Just one additional question. I don't really understand why this causes the memory leak. Shouldn't the end of the session automatically free the memory?

Comment: You are welcome. I am not sure but I think that might be just the way the Python [garbage collector works](https://rushter.com/blog/python-garbage-collector/). My intuition tells me it is much better not to recreate a new session object in every loop iteration (wich is what happens when using `with tf.Session() as sess:`, instead simply create the session object once before the loop with `sess = tf.Session()` and reuse it on every loop iteration.